# How can I add a click event to a class in Vue **without** changing the html?

Tags: vue.js

I'm brand new to Vue, so I'm not sure if this is a super-basic or can't-be-done question.  I need to take existing HTML content code and wrap it with a vue app.  This much is working great!  The trouble comes where the code has used a simple jQuery toggle to show/hide child divs. I need to know how to mimic this behaviour in vue **without** adding a ref or @click or anything like that to the existing XML/HTML: I can't change that at all.  Is it possible to mimic this behaviour in Vue? Thanks very much in advance ... :)

Here's the existing jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.toggle > *').hide();
  $('.toggle .header').show();
  $('.toggle .header').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children().not('.header').toggle(400);
    $(this).parent().children('.header').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Here's the HTML (which can't be changed!!):

```
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="header">Click me to show the div!</div>
  <div class="someClass">Some div content to be toggled</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS (which can be changed):

```
.toggle .header {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.toggle .header p:after {
    content: " +";
}

.toggle .header.open p:after {
    content: " -";
}
```

Comment: You can do everything programmatically with Javascript and vue.js is just a framework.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for the quick response!  I actually tried that one before posting the question, but couldn't get it to find my element at all!  Now, looking at it again I've seen that I didn't trigger it from the `mounted` function, so it was never being run.  Thanks!

Comment: Avoid using jQuery with Vue